# ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -m/--mode

Tags: python, argparse

I have a long code and I keep getting this error when I run it. does anyone know what is this error about?

`    usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -m MODE

```
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -m/--mode

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
 
SystemExit: 2`
```

Comment: Looks like you are starting a `jupyter-notebook` that has an `argparse` commandline parser.  That won't work.  Commandline values that you give when launching `jupyter` are for the server only.  This code might work as a regular python script if given commandline arguments as suggested by the `usage`.

Comment: @hpaulj  I get the same error when I use ipython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `ipython` help:

```
ipython [subcommand] [options] [-c cmd | -m mod | file] [--] [arg] ...
```

So we can call a script that echos `sys.argv` with:

```
0812:~/mypy$ ipython echo.py -- foo bar
['/home/paul/mypy/echo.py', 'foo', 'bar']
```

or to stay in an interactive session:

```
0812:~/mypy$ ipython echo.py -- foo bar
['/home/paul/mypy/echo.py', 'foo', 'bar']
0824:~/mypy$ ipython -i echo.py -- foo bar
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
['/home/paul/mypy/echo.py', 'foo', 'bar']

In [1]: sys.argv
Out[1]: ['/usr/local/bin/ipython', '-i', 'echo.py', '--', 'foo', 'bar']
```

`sys.argv` contains the commandline strings that your `argparse` parser will process.  Just provide the values it expects (as specified in the `usage`).

Answer (score 0):

i have same error while running jupyter notebook how to resolve this error.

1. open command line interface.
2. copy the path where your python is been installed.
3. write cd in command line interface and past the path of installed python exe.
4. while entering to that path in command line interface after that write command pip install jupyter after that wait for a moment to install new version of jupyter.